# C# lambda allocation and collection

Tags: .net, lambda, garbage-collection, clr, micro-optimization

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38726231/1488067) today about some performance difference regarding `ConcurrentDictionary` methods, and I saw it as a premature micro-optimization.

However, upon some thought, I realized (if I am not mistaken), that each time we pass a lambda to a method, CLR needs to allocate the memory, pass the appropriate closure (if needed), and then collect it some time later.

There are three possibilities:

1. Lambda without a closure:

   ```
   // the lambda should internally compile to a static method, 
   // but will CLR instantiate a new ManagedDelegate wrapper or
   // something like that?
   return concurrent_dict.GetOrAdd(key, k => ValueFactory(k));
   ```
2. Lambda with a closure:

   ```
   // this is definitely an allocation
   return concurrent_dict.GetOrAdd(key, k => ValueFactory(k, stuff));
   ```
3. Outside check (like checking the condition before the lock):

   ```
   // no lambdas in the hot path
   if (!concurrent_dict.TryGetValue(key, out value))
       return concurrent_dict.GetOrAdd(key, k => ValueFactory(k));
   ```

Third case is obviously allocation-free, the second one will need an allocation.

But is the first case (lambda which doesn't have a capture) completely allocation-free (at least in newer CLR versions)? Also, is this an implementation detail of the runtime, or something specified by the standard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all the CLR does not know what a lambda is. This is a C# concept. It is compiled away. The C# language provides you a delegate value where you wrote the lambda.

C# does not guarantee that the delegate instance (or underlying method) is shared or not. In fact I believe the initialization of shared lambda delegates is thread unsafe and racy. So depending on timing you might see just one or multiple delegate instances.

So it's an implementation detail of the language.

In practice you can rely on forms 1 and 3 being shared. This is important for performance. If this ever was not the case I think it would be considered a high priority bug.

Comment: TLDR: Forms 1 and 3 require O(1) allocations, because it is compiled to a single static method.

Comment: Note that if you just use the name of the method without the lambda, there *will* be an allocation every time: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6662729/5749914

Answer (score 2):

If by allocation you mean to the generated `DisplayClass`, so the first case will be allocation free. But it still need some allocation, the `Func<Key, Value>` for example.

> 6.5.3 Implementation example
>
> ```
> public delegate void D();
> ```
>
> The simplest form of an anonymous function is one that captures no outer variables:
>
> ```
> class Test
> {
>     static void F() {
>         D d = () => { Console.WriteLine("test"); };
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> This can be translated to a delegate instantiation that references a compiler generated static method in which the code of the anonymous function is placed:
>
> ```
> class Test
> {
>     static void F() {
>         D d = new D(__Method1);
>     }
>     static void __Method1() {
>         Console.WriteLine("test");
>     }
> }
> ```

If you want to check what happening in each case, (static\instance field, locals, this, shared generated objects)

take a look at [C# specification](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029), Section **6.5.3 Implementation example** of Anonymous functions